# C: Incomplete return type

Tags: c, struct, declaration

I tried to implement linked list in C, and started with this simple code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct int_node;
struct int_list;
struct int_list create_list();

int main() {

    struct int_list list = create_list();
    return 0;
}

struct int_node {
    int value;
    struct int_node * next;
};

struct int_list {
    struct int_node * first;
};

struct int_list create_list() {
    /* Creates an empty list, first node=null */
    struct int_list list;
    list.first = NULL;
    return list;
};
```

While building I got two errors:

1. Calling 'create_list' with incomplete return type 'struct int_list'
2. Variable has incomplete type 'struct int_list'

I looked for an answer and all I could find was that I need to declare the structs and the functions before I use them, which I did.

Another thing I tried was to move the main() function to the end, and that solved the errors, but it's a silly workaround and I want to find out the real solution.

Any help?

Comment: C is designed in a way allowing one-pass compilation. And at the point, where you declare an object, the type must be complete, which your structure isn't at the declaration in `main`. That the type is completed later, doesn't help.

Comment: (Unrelated) Are you aware that you are returning a local variable in `create_list`?

Comment: @Jongware Yes, fixed that later on - thanks!

Comment: remove the forward declarations for the struct declarations.  move the actual struct declarations to before the main() function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The definitions of the structs should also be placed before `main()`. That is, your silly fix is actually the correct fix.

Comment: Thank you! Does it always have to be like that?
(Sorry if it sounds like a silly question, I'm just starting with C)

Comment: @MatanAbudy: Generally. There are some cases where a forward declaration is sufficient, but I probably wouldn't worry about that for now.

Comment: Yes, always. In good C source code, the code is at the bottom (after definitions of `struct`, `typedef`, etc...)

Comment: As a rule, I always try to put struct definitions before everything else in the file (besides #include's). I find that it's easier to read than having them spread out throughout the code and it avoids errors like this

Comment: So, if I'm defining the struct before everything else, is there any need for a declaration?

Comment: Correct. They are not necessary here.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you need to **define** the structs before you use them, or else how does the compiler know what a `struct int_node` is when it sees it in the main method. So as Bill Lynch said your simple fix is actually just the correct way.

You should look in to how exactly a program goes from source code to an executable in C if you are interested in learning more. [Here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/10/c-program-to-an-executable/) is an interesting and not to long page about it.